# How to add touch event for a Layout that contains a ScrollView

Tags: android, layout, scrollview, touch-event

The problem is the the scrolling will intercept with touch event has set to the parent `layout`.
Can I keep the `onTouch` event with the scroll in `ScrollView` ?

Answer (score 3):

This is a very tricky part. There is an overriden method from `Activity` which is: `public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)`

This is the general method that interprets all the touch events from the whole screen. And you could say, "ok, I can implement this and I am good to go..". And here comes the difficult part on how android works.

As you know every `View` has its own `onTouchEvent()` method that you could implement in order to add some custom implementation. So which method will listen? The `ScrollView` or the `Activity`? It appears that these touch events go from the "inside" elements to the "outside" elements. I mean parent-child relations.

Another thing to take into account is that the onTouchEvent method returns a boolean. This boolean parameter determines whether the touch event should go one level up or it is handled by the current `View`. Meaning that if you have a `CustomViewA` that implements the onTouchEvent() and `CustomViewB` implementing its own touch event, and the A is a child in B then the touch event would go through A first and if it is not handled it would go to B.

So basically yes it could be done. It depends on what touch event you wanted to do.

So in our case, the `ScrollView` returns `true` when the touch events are a horizontal. The activity's touch event will be handled only if the `ScrollView` touch event is not handled by itself then you are fine. Otherwise you have to override and implement the on touch event of scroll view and in some cases you have to return false so as for the whole layout to implement it. Good luck with the last part. I started to implement a fling effect but came up with some difficulties so I have implemented a 2 finger move with scroll view in it and it works like a charm.

This is about a week of research and experimenting and it is an overview of what I came up with. if you find anything else please let me know. Hope it helped.